# how to change colors of navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

i want to change the color of the text when i hover on it
i tried

```
li:hover
{
color:#....;
}
```

but it didnt work here's my  html

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#"><font face="segoeui, Verdana, Tahoma" size="+1">Home</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font face="segoeui, Verdana, Tahoma" size="+1">Shop</a></font></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font face="segoeui, Verdana, Tahoma" size="+1">Blog</a></font></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font face="segoeui, Verdana, Tahoma" size="+1">Contact</a></font></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

and here's my css

#nav {
width: 100%;
height:70px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;
background: #151515; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%, #151515 37%, #151515 47%, #1a1a1a 61%, #222222 73%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#151515), color-stop(37%,#151515), color-stop(47%,#151515), color-stop(61%,#1a1a1a), color-stop(73%,#222222)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#151515', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
}

#nav li a {
padding: 15px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color:#FFF;
}

ul.navigation {
background-color:#000;
width:200px;
height:30px;
}
```

and here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jyNHm/

i want that when you hover on the text it gives an awesome effect of color.

Comment: i want to make that when Home is selected it displays a color

Comment: You color declaration for `#nav li a` takes precedence over the color you are trying to apply via `li:hover` …

Comment: i want to make that when Home is selected it displays a color @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you only want the text to change color, or the background.

So here's both!

---

### For the background:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyNHm/5/

Instead of using

```
#nav li:hover {
#color:...
}
```

use

```
#nav li:hover {
background-color:...
}
```

---

### For the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyNHm/6/

Instead of

```
#nav li:hover {
color:...
}
```

use

```
#nav li a:hover {
color:...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
#nav a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/jyNHm/3/

Comment: i want the selected link to appear the same color of hover i tried a:active but it doesnt work can you edit it please?

Comment: :active only changes color if you hold down the mouse on it, check http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/jyNHm/4/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the font tag within the li tag. use CSS on the font tag instead, and that will fix your problem:

```
font:hover {
    color:#999999}
```